# If $S_1$ and $S_2$ both span subspace $W$ and $S_2$ is linear combination of $S_1$, how do we show that $W=$span$(S_1) \iff W=$span$(S_2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $S_1$ and $S_2$ both span subspace $W$ and $S_2$ is linear combination of $S_1$, how do we show that $W=$span$(S_1) \iff W=$span$(S_2)$?

$\Rightarrow$ Since $S_1$ linearly combines to form $S_2$, If $S_1$ spans $W$, that means $S_2$ can also linearly combines to span $W$.

$\Leftarrow$ same reasoning?

Could someone give some ideas for how to solve?

Comment: I'm assuming $S_1$ and $S_2$ are sets of vectors.  What precisely do you mean by $S_2$ is a linear combination of $S_1$.  My understanding is that a linear combination is a single vector.

Comment: When you say $S_2$ is a linear combination of $S_1$, do you mean that every vector in $S_2$ can be represented by a linear combination of the vectors in $S_1$?